# Traffic is not shown with custom tiles - iOS Google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps

I have a map in my app, implemented with Google Maps iOS SDK. Traffic is perfectly works with Google tiles (normal, hybrid, satellite, etc.), but nothing happens when i set my custom tiles. What can be wrong?

Code for custom tiles (tiles itself loads correctly):

```
let urls: GMSTileURLConstructor = {(x, y, zoom) in
                let url = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/\(zoom)/\(x)/\(y).png"
                return URL(string: url)
            }

            let layer = GMSURLTileLayer(urlConstructor: urls)
            layer.map = mapView
```

Code for trigging traffic:

```
func toggleShowTraffic(status: Bool) {
        mapView.isTrafficEnabled = status
    }
```